# Convert GraphQLResponse to class

Tags: c#, graphql

I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction, basically I'm trying to *map* a GraphQL response to class. This is my GraphQL response

[image]

and I'm trying to map the data in the 'node' array to

```
public class Course
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously I could loop through the array and add them individually but is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks,
S

Comment: I don't think so - you're going to have to create each class element one at a time from the array afaict.